# Running poetry in jenkinsfile

Tags: python, jenkins, kubernetes, python-poetry

Setup is Jenkins running in Kubernetes.  I want to lint my code, run my tests, then build a container.  Having trouble getting poetry to install/run in one of my build steps.

```
podTemplate(inheritFrom: 'k8s-slave', containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'py38', image: 'python:3.8.4-slim-buster', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')
  ]) 
{
    node(POD_LABEL) {

        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout scm
            sh 'ls -lah'
        }

        container('py38') {
            stage('Poetry Configuration') {
                sh 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl'
                sh "curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python"
                sh "$HOME/.poetry/bin/poetry install --no-root"
                sh "$HOME/.poetry/bin/poetry shell --no-interaction"
            }

            stage('Lint') {
                sh 'pre-commit install'
                sh "pre-commit run --all"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Poetry install works fine, but when I go to activate the shell, it fails.

```
+ /root/.poetry/bin/poetry shell --no-interaction
Spawning shell within /root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/truveris-version-Zr2qBFRU-py3.8

[error]
(25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Comment: Total guess, but do you also need to add `--no-interaction` to `poetry install`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that Jenkins runs a non-interactive shell and you are trying to start an interactive shell. The `--no-interaction` option doesn't mean a non-interactive shell but rather the shell not asking you questions:

```sh
  -n (--no-interaction)  Do not ask any interactive question
```

[This answer explains it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54012557/2989261) .

I would just not call the shell and just use the `poetry run`  command:

```
podTemplate(inheritFrom: 'k8s-slave', containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'py38', image: 'python:3.8.4-slim-buster', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')
  ]) 
{
    node(POD_LABEL) {

        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout scm
            sh 'ls -lah'
        }

        container('py38') {
            stage('Poetry Configuration') {
                sh 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl'
                sh "curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python"
                sh "$HOME/.poetry/bin/poetry install --no-root"
            }

            stage('Lint') {
                sh "$HOME/.poetry/bin/poetry run 'pre-commit install'"
                sh "$HOME/.poetry/bin/poetry run 'pre-commit run --all'"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

✌️

Comment: great answer, if running Jenkins behind a firewall where your cluster doesn't have access to anything external (only intranet sites) - should change the install to pip, which may result in less config.

Answer (score 0):

Install poetry on container level and then parse the poetry.lock file with

```
poetry export --without-hashes --dev -f requirements.txt -o requirements.txt
```

Then install the dependencies with `pip install -r requirements.txt` INSTEAD of `poetry install`

Then you don't have to run your commands in the virtual env.